# What would happen if many asteroids with a combined mass equal to ten times that of Jupiter were dumped into the Solar System?

Tags: science-based, space

One day, numerous asteroids inexplicably appear out of nowhere in the Solar System, distributed evenly in a ring between Earth and Mars. The asteroids are a mix of primarily carbonaceous, stony, and nickel-iron asteroids, and range in size from specks of dust to dwarf planets the size of Titan. Their total mass equals ten times the mass of Jupiter. What happens to the solar system? Will they aggregate into one or more new planets? How large of a rocky planet could they form? Would any of them get flung off to strike other planets?

Comment: What timescale are you interested in?  The timeline of the evolution of the solar system is quite different than the timeline of, say, NASA or humans.  Also, I will note that the answer to what happens after the rocks get put in place is actually quite a lot less interesting than the question of what the {bleepity} {bleep} managed to move those rocks there in the first place!

Comment: This is too broad and impossible to answer in any useful way.  There are unlimited variations depending on the *details*.

Comment: It seems that there is a huge range of possible outcomes depending on variables which are simply not explored in the question. Voting to close as too broad. (From review).

Comment: Are those asteroids at rest (and then, at rest relative to what?) or are they in motion? If, for example, they are at rest with respect to the galactic center they will leave the solar system in quite a hurry, because the solar system revolves around the galactic center with an orbital velocity of about 220 km/sec.

Comment: This is why our solar system has a "No Dumping" sign right over there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is over a million times more massive than the [Asteroid belt between Jupiter and Mars](https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/asteroids-comets-and-meteors/asteroids/in-depth/). To summarize the calculations below,  **we're not getting to Mars.**

Gravitational attraction between two masses $m_1$ and $m_2$ (that are seperated by a distance of $d$) is defined by the following equation:

$ F = 6.67*10^{-11} * \frac{m_1 * m_2}{d^2}$

That annoying little constant at the start means that **any two objects smaller than a megatonne aren't really going to drift towards one another.** In fact:

$Jupiter_{mass} = 1.90 * 10^{27} kg$

$Area\ between\ Earth's\ and Mars'\ orbit = \pi *  (r_{marsOrbit}^2 - r_{earthOrbit}^2)$

$ = 9.29 * 10 ^ {16} km^2 $

In an even distribution, this gives an average of **20.4 gigatonnes of asteroid per square kilometre.** Mars 2024 isn't looking good here. Aside from rocket navigation, there won't be many clear radio signals getting through here.

Let's say your asteroids produce a resultant force directly at the asteroid belt's centre. Using Kepler's Third Law, and taking the mean force of the belt times the size of the belt:

$\frac{T^2}{r^3} = \frac{4\pi^2}{GM}$

$Mars -> 3.12*10^{-19}$

$Mars\ with\ asteroid\ belt - > 3.08 * 10^{-19}$

$ change = 1.14\% $

Congratulations, **you've just reduced the time period of Mars' solar orbit by four days.** This is assuming a circular orbit, constant radius of orbit and other simplifications, but it should give you an idea of how absolutely massive an asteroid field this is.

It could be a lot of use in your story, as it would certainly encourage colonisation efforts of planets like Venus or force scientists to somehow punch a hole through space in order to escape our solar system.

Comment: An enjoyable exercise in analytic thinking. One point that may need a rethink. It's not mass per square kilometre that's important. It's the density per cubic kilometre that counts. If there are Titan-mass objects, the effective average density will be lowered. Had it been a dust belt, there would be a lot of stuff getting in the way of a Mars mission.

Comment: Completely fair point- was allowing for flexibility in question (as no real dimensions are specified by OP) but you're completely right that volume and density trump surface area. +1

Comment: "density per cubic kilometre"?  You meant "mass per cubic km, right?

Comment: "density per cubic kilometre"?  You meant "mass per cubic km, right?

Comment: @krb Right, you're right. My fingers tripped over themselves. I think I was trying to say density in terms of cubic kms, or something like that. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 9):

In the short term the planets Earth and Mars would be subjected to the equivalent of the [Late Heavy Bombardment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_Heavy_Bombardment). Initially Earth's skies will be filled with magnificent displays of shooting stars. Well, until dinosaur-killer sized rocks come our way.

Basically the surfaces of Earth and Mars will be significantly rearranged. Life will become impossible. Time for the human species build lost and lots of spaceships and move to quieter, safer parts of the universe. This could be the moons of the outer planets. They might be far enough away from the Hell of an asteroid-congested inner solar system could become, to provide habitats for the human exodus.

Most of this will occur because of gravitational perturbation of the orbits of the asteroids in the newly formed Earth-Mars asteroid belt. The main perturbing planets will be Earth and Mars, and especially the planet Jupiter itself. Dust, and asteroids will be drawn to the nearest gravitating objects. That is, Earth and Mars.

Considering there are Titan-mass sized asteroids these will 'siphon' matter from this massive asteroid belt. Gradually they will develop into higher-mass objects. Possibly, becoming super-Earths (in terms of mass) and eventually gas-giant-mass objects, but without the massive atmospheres of the gas giants.

The mass of the new asteroid belt will gravitationally perturb the planets of the solar system into new orbits. The planets of the inner solar system will be drawn into higher orbits closer to the new high-mass asteroid belt. Correspondingly, the planets of the outer solar system will settle into lower orbits closer to the Sun. This is due to the fact that ten Jupiter masses is approximately equivalent to one percent of the Sun's mass.

The survival of intelligent life in the solar system will be determined by its space-faring capability. Planets of the inner solar system will become relatively rapidly uninhabitable. Survival inside the Earth's crust may be possible, but the engineering problems to be overcome are certainly non-trivial. Exodus to the outer solar system is also, definitely, a non-trivial exercise.

Many of the changes to the solar system will be difficult to estimate. Not without conducting a significant exercise in computer simulation. This requires an accurate knowledge of the distribution of sizes and masses of the newly arrived asteroids. The effects discussed above can be deduced based on the past history of the solar system.

Comment: Jupiter's mass is 0.1% of the Sun's mass, so 10 Jupiters would be 1% of the Sun's mass.

Comment: @RichardSmith Thank you for correction. I will edit accordingly.

Comment: "_the surfaces of Earth and Mars will be significantly rearranged_" A brilliant understatement - I love it!

Answer (score 5):

Fact 1: the space between Mars and Earth is kept clean by those two planets gravitational influence

Fact 2: 10 times the mass of Jupiter is a lot, I don't remember it out of my mind but might be enough to trigger stellar formation if made of hydrogen.

You have then 2 scenarios in the long term.

Scenario 1: Earth and Mars swipe the space faster than the mass accretes, getting a fair share of bombardment in the process. Life is doomed.

Scenario 2: the accretion goes faster than the swiping. Earth and Mars for sure are now the debris which get swiped out of their orbit. Life is doomed.